# Gulp sass workflow

Tags: node.js, gulp

Can't get the hang of what is wrong with my workflow.

Can it be that i need to do this in 2 steps?
First compile sass and concat them.
When they are contatinated i will autoprefix, minimize and add sourcemaps?

The delete part is for removing the compiled sass files, i will only need my concatinated files in release configuration.

Error:

> ```
> > Error: Task compileSass can't support dependencies that is not an
> > array of strings
> >     at Gulp.Orchestrator.add (C:\Dev\***\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:47:10)
> >     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\***\gulpfile.js:32:6)
> >     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
> >     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
> >     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
> >     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
> >     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
> >     at require (module.js:380:17)
> >     at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Dev\***\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
> >     at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\***\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)
> >     at module.exports (C:\Dev\***\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
> ```

```
module.exports = function (project) {

    // Shorten base names.
    const config = project.gulp.config;
    const plugins = project.plugins;
    const paths = project.gulp.paths;
    const webroot = project.webroot;

    // Shorten plug-in names.
    const gulp = plugins.gulp;
    const sourcemaps = plugins.sourcemaps;
    const concat = plugins.concat;
    const del = plugins.del;
    const rename = plugins.rename;
    const minify = plugins.minify;
    const autoprefixer = plugins.autoprefixer;
    const log = plugins.util.log;

    // Shorten path names.
    const source = paths.sassSource;
    const output = webroot + paths.sassOutput;

    // Checks the current configuration and execute its stream.
    if (config === 'Production') {
        return function() {
            gulp.src(source)
                .pipe(plugins.sass())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(autoprefixer())
                .pipe(minify())
                .pipe(concat('successful.planr.min.css'))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
                .pipe(del([output + '/*/**']).then(function (paths) {
                    log('Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
                }));
        }
    } else {
        return function() {
            // Will load my development configuration.    
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that autoprefixer is using es6 promises.

Solved the issue by installing npm package 'es6-promise' and the added the following line.

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```